# Moving pictureboxes without creating a PictureBox_MouseDown for every single one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, picturebox, mousedown

I have a lot of pictureboxes I want to move individually. Creating a MouseDown method for each picturebox will get messy.

Is there any way I can get the name of the picturebox I click, and move it to the next spot I click? Or have it follow the mouse on MouseDown and dropped if that's better.

Thanks

Comment: Have them all use the same MouseDown method and use the sender parameter to figure out which one is calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same method for them all:

```
private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBoxName = (sender as PictureBox).Name;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add. How can I edit the BackColor for that picturebox when I only have a string?

Comment: PictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
        HookEvents( this );
```

on Form_Load()

After that, you need to add this

```
    private void HookEvents( Control Parent )
    {
        foreach ( Control Child in Parent.Controls )
        {
            if ( Child is PictureBox )
            {
                Child.MouseDown += new EventHandler( OnPictureBoxMouseDown );
                if ( Child.Controls.Count > 0 )
                {
                    HookEvents( Child );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And Add ( Possible to add as private and so on, just I prefer to use public )

```
public void OnPictureBoxMouseDown( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
// blah blah
}
```